# Akka : TestKit.fishForMessage random timeout failures

Tags: akka

We use TestKit for testing our application and there are seems random timeout failures during running tests

**timeout (10016 milliseconds) during fishForMessage**

*testKit.fishForMessage(duration, "", events);*

I tried to increase duration, but it did not help.

Any ideas of fixing such problem ?

Comment: Do you know that the expected message is actually being sent?

Comment: yes, it should be sent, because the test is green in most runs, just sometimes it fails

Comment: If you're sure that it's eventually being sent, the only thing you can really do is keep increasing the duration.  In a particularly complex test (or on an overloaded system where the test is running), timeouts will need to be loosened.

Comment: As always, it's impossible in general to tell the difference between "failed" and "slow"

Comment: yeah, it is also strange that I was able to "fix" it on local machine, but still failing on Jenkins pipeline even with 2 mins timeout.